# Partition algorithm

Tags: java, recursion

I am receiving **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10** after running this code.

How can I limit my code to only `9` index values or find an alternative way to correct this?

```
int p = theArray[first]; // use the first item of the array as the pivot p      
int lastS1 = first;      // set S1 and S2 to empty

// ToDo: Determine the regions S1 and S2
// Refer to the partition algorithm on page 495 of the textbook.

for (int i = lastS1; i < last; i++)
    if (theArray[i] < p) {
        for (int j = i ; j > 0 && j >= p ; j--)
            swap(theArray, j, j - 1);
    }

lastS1++;

return lastS1;
```

Comment: Please indent your code and give a workable example, this one just not have the definition of the function

Comment: Seems your code is incomplete: what is the value of 'first'?

Comment: Code has been indented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for (int i = lastS1; i < last - 1; i++)`.

You need to use `last - 1` because in Java, arrays are `0` indexed. Means they start from 0 and go to length - 1.

Comment: While this might prevent the exception, would you please add a slightly more detailed explanation why you think that this implements the intended behavior of the algorithm?